# Eigenfunctions of the integral kernel 1/(x^2 + x'^2)

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, integral-equations, eigenfunctions

My question seems elementary, yet I could not find the solution after working on and searching for several days...
I'd like to find the eigenfunctions of a simple integral kernel:
\begin{equation}
\lambda f_\lambda(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{d x'}{x^2 +x'^2} f_\lambda(x')
\end{equation}
There is an obvious scaling property
\begin{equation}
f_{\lambda'}(x)=f_{\lambda}(x \lambda/\lambda'),
\end{equation}
so it suffice to find an eigenfunction at a certain $\lambda$.

It looks like the theory of complex functions may be of help here, and $f(x)$ can be analytically continued to the half-plane ${\rm Re} z >0$, from the line ${\rm Im}z =0$, ${\rm Re}z >0$. One can thus derive an equation relating the values of $f(z)$ at  this line and the line ${\rm Im}(z)=0$,
\begin{equation}
\lambda \left(f(-i x+ \delta) - f(i x + \delta)\right) = \frac{i}{2 x} f(x);
\end{equation}
$x>0$, $\delta>0, \delta \to 0$. However, I am not able to guess the solution of this equation.

**Update:**

With some sweat, I've obtained the asymptotic expression at small $x$ ($\lambda = 1/2)$,
\begin{equation}
f(x) \propto x^{-1/2} \cos\left(\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\pi} \right).
\end{equation}
No further progress so far.

**Update 2:**

The asymptotic expression at big $x$:
\begin{equation}
f(x) \propto \frac{1}{x^2} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{4\lambda x} + \frac{\ln(\lambda x)}{8 \pi (\lambda x)^2}\right) + O(x^{-4}) 
\end{equation}

Comment: Have you proved that they exist?

Comment: No, I have not: strict mathematical proof is beyond my skill. Yet I have no reason to believe that they do not exist for that well-behaved kernel (would appreciate if somebody gives me one). Besides, numerical results show reasonable convergence upon varying the discretization fineness.

Comment: Is it really that well behaved? Usually one wants a condition that a kernel is integrable over the whole domain i.e  $\int_{0}^\infty\int_0^\infty k(x,y)dxdy$ should converge. In you case this doesn't happen. If there are any solutions they must rapidly decrease at $0$. Are you looking for continous solutions defined on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Eventually, it should increase and oscillate upon approaching 0, see the update. Yes, it's continuous except x=0.

Comment: I think if you let the domain be $I=(\epsilon,\infty)$ for some $\epsilon>0$, then you can define an operator $K:L^2(I) \to L^2(I)$, whose eigenvalues are your eigenfunctions. Maybe some spectral theory might help you. (The operator is self-adjoint)

Comment: also asked at https://mathoverflow.net/q/453889/11260

Comment: @BenS. I've updated the asymptotes at small/large $x$: perhaps those would convince you.